# How to save a Type in string format

Tags: c#

How do I save a `Type` in string format?

```
public class cat
{
    public int i = 1;
    public func ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am a cat");
    }

}

// ...

Type obj_type = typeof(cat);
string arg2;

arg2 = obj_type.ToString(); /* error*/
arg2 = (string)obj_type;/*same error*/
arg2 = obj_type.Name; /*same error*/

Console.WriteLine(obj_type); /*ok*/ " temp.cat "
```

I receive this error at the line above:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Type'

Comment: That is not where the error occurs. This compiles and runs.

Comment: The line you marked as an error definitely is not giving the error. You're probably passing the string to a method expecting a type.

Comment: If function expects `Type` then you can't just pass it `string`, there is no magic to do that.

Comment: Can I ask why you are even trying to pass a type as a string? your use of `CreateInstance` makes me  think you are really looking for generics

Comment: Where do you use the `arg2`? So far you haven't shown where you use the string and the error **actually** originates from.

Comment: The only line containing an error is `arg2 = (string)obj_type;` and it is `Cannot convert type 'System.Type' to 'string'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the *fully qualified type name* try this:

`arg2 = obj_type.AssemblyQualifiedName;`

Answer (score 1):

You can get type of instantiated object:

```
string typeName = obj.GetType().Name;
```

MSDN reference to `GetType` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx

And in case you want to get Type name just by Class:

```
private static void ShowTypeInfo(Type t)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", t.Name);
   Console.WriteLine("Full Name: {0}", t.FullName);
   Console.WriteLine("ToString:  {0}", t.ToString());
   Console.WriteLine("Assembly Qualified Name: {0}",
                       t.AssemblyQualifiedName);
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, just checked it :

```
Type obj_type = typeof(cat);
string arg2 = obj_type.ToString();
// arg2 = obj_type.Name; it works too and it gives short name without namespaces
Console.WriteLine(arg2);
```

Output: `Test1.cat`  // fully qualified name

P.S.

```
arg2 = (string)obj_type;
```

Here you try to explicitly cast Type to string. It's like you say "Hey i am 100% sure that Type can be converted to string easily so just do it". It's not working because there is no simple conversion between them and compiler doesn't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

typeof accept a Type not its instance.

See This.

```
public class cat
{
    public int i = 1;
    public void func()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am a cat");
    }
}

Type type = typeof(cat);// typeof accept a Type not its instance
string typeName = type.Name;// cat
```